# Can't write the set-operator in mathjax?

Tags: support, mathjax

When trying to write $\{1,2,3\}$ in a question on math.stackexchange.com it just becomes $1,2,3$. However it seems to work here on meta.math.stackexchange.com. How can I get it to work on the main-site?

The preview of the post has also become very slow lately. Maybe it is connected?

Comment: Are you sure you used `\{` and `\}` to get the delimiters? I cannot reproduce the problem. It works just as it should for me.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I would think so since the OP were able to write this question correctly and compare both effects. I think it happened to me several times that the browser refuses to understand MathJax and became slow - but in that case iirc I would see the whole code, ie including both `\ ` and  `{`.

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudMortier. I apologize for jumping the gun. May be this is one of those situations, where reloading the page is necessary? Rethinking, I may have experienced similar problems. I don't remember this particular one. Anyway, reloading usually helped with those.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example of a post on main where this happened? Or is this just in the preview?

Comment: I tried to do it again and it seems to work now. It was just in a preview it happened. Lately the previews have been very slow on the main site, but here on meta they seem to work fast. I guess it is easier to write tge post on meta and then just copy it when it is done.

Comment: I’ve had the issue of some symbols not rendering properly on my browser lately. I believe this is what is happening to the OP. Refreshing the page seems to fix the problem.